# Word 2007 has highjacked my RTF association to Jarte Pro

Tags: windows-vista, rtf

64-bit Vista
I have both Word 2007 and Jarte Pro. I have used Default Programs > Set Associations in Vista to associate RTF with Jarte Pro. However, when clicking on an RTF file in Explorer, it opens in Word 2007. Is there any way to correct this, other than to uninstall Word? :)

===============================================================================

After much back and forth with Jarte's developer, he determined that:

"The error you are encountering appears to be due to a problem Jarte is having communicating with your printer. However, I don't know why this would only be happening when you start Jarte by clicking on a file. I will have to investigate this further. Meanwhile, try downloading and installing the latest printer driver for your printer and see if that helps."

I did have the latest driver. He will correct the problem with the next version of Jarte (a terrific program, BTW).

Answer (score 0):

Use **Types** is a free utility that allows you to edit program associations, icons, context menus and other properties of various file types displayed in Windows Explorer.

[image]

[Download it form here](http://types.sourceforge.net/)

JNK Edit:

Info on **Types** in this answer is from [This web site.](http://www.windowsreference.com/free-utilities/howto-edit-program-associations-icons-context-menus-in-vistaxp/)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find the link for downloading Types. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I use Nirsoft's freeware [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) to manage file type associations.

Comment: I downloaded it, but it doesn't list the very extensions I'm concerned with here: .rtf and .docx . Also .jpg, .png, .txt (has .text instead?), etc.